# Concatenating 4 rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this :

```
Date         OPEN CLOSE HIGH LOW
12.12.2017   10   0     0     0
12.12.2017   0    20    0     0
12.12.2017   0    0    20     0
12.12.2017   0    0     0    10
```

How can I combine them in one row in another table ?
Thank you

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: 12.12.2017   10  20   20   10

Comment: Please explain the logic behind your result. Otherwise you might get an answer like `SELECT '12.12.2017 10 20 20 10'`.

Answer (score 0):

If for any date there is only one non zero value for every other column, then you can GROUP BY `Date` and use `SUM()` for other columns:

```
SELECT
   Date,
   SUM(OPEN) as OPEN,
   SUM(CLOSE) as CLOSE,
   SUM(HIGH) as HIGH,
   SUM(LOW) as LOW
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Date
```

But in that case I would store the data in a different way. For example:

```
Date         Type   Value
-------------------------
12.12.2017   OPEN      10
12.12.2017   CLOSE     20
12.12.2017   HIGH      20
12.12.2017   LOW       10
```